# Python 3: Error while executing os.rename()

Tags: python, windows, file, rename

I am trying to rename files using this code:

```
def rename_files(src: str,dst: str, folder_name: str):
    filepath = f"temp/{src}"
    filepath = filepath.replace("/", "\\")
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    old_path = os.path.join(cwd, filepath)
    newfilepath = f"folder/{folder_name}/{dst}.pdf"
    newfilepath = newfilepath.replace("/", "\\")
    new_path = os.path.join(cwd, newfilepath)
    if os.path.exists(old_path):
        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
    else:
        print("File does not exist")
```

While executing it, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'E:\\Repos\\GitHub\\source\\t2dm\\temp\\oldfilename.pdf' -> 'E:\\Repos\\GitHub\\source\\t2dm\\folder\\subfolder\\newfilename.pdf'
```

The code is being executed from:

```
E:\Repos\GitHub\source\t2dm\
```

The file `oldfilename.pdf` exists in `E:\Repos\GitHub\source\t2dm\temp\`, and `folder\subfolder` also exists.

What to do to resolve this?

Edit: added some more information regarding `folder\subfolder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new folder `folder_name` does not exist, `os.rename` won't create it.

You can do one of:

1. use [`os.renames()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.renames) (note the `s`), instead of `os.rename` in that line of your code - which will create the directories for the destination if they don't already exist.
2. use [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to make the dir tree for the subfolders.

If you aren't creating multiple dir trees, then option (1) is ideal for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the rapid and detailed response! The new folder does exist. That's why I cannot understand what is happening.

Comment: Then there's information missing from your post. If the source and dest folders exist and the source pdf exists, this shouldn't fail. Is the code in your post **_exactly the same_** as what you're executing? Copy both the paths in the error message and open each in windows File Explorer. Also check that you have the necessary permissions, if it's an external drive or a network share. Can't help further than that.

Comment: No, I resolved the error. The new filename was problematic. When I tested the code with something else, it worked instantly. Thanks.